# Can't save any WordPress post with the html tag in it

Tags: html

I'm working with WordPress 4.9.6 and i have a problem for 2 days... 
I can't save any post if there is the html tag inside with editor or not, i mean `&lt;html&gt;` or `<html>`. If i try to save, i have an error page not found.

I can write other html tags with no problem, it's only the html one wich give me difficulties...

I have tried :

- disable every plugins
- Save my permalink again...
- Change the version of PHP (i work with O2Switch with PHP 7.2)

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try [reverting to an older WordPress version](http://dominiquej.com/how-to-downgrade-wordpress-to-previous-version/)? That should work if the problem relates to something breaking in the 4.9.6 version (unless somebody here confirms otherwise).

Comment: No, i haven't try this...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is arrived with the 4.9.7 update of WordPress.